# Decorators error in VS code editor after upgrading to Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

```
Error: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.
```

In Angular 9 with same project no such error was there.

Angular10 has now added tsconfig.base.json file.

`tsconfig.json` file updated as:

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json:**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.base.json:`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
  }
}
```

I noticed that content of `tsconfig.json` in Angular 9 has been moved to `tsconfig.base.json` in Angular 10.

Comment: Did you fix this error? can you share your solution if you did.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was having the same issue in VSCode with Angular 10 freshly installed, I checked and experimental decorator was already added, but still, I was getting that annoying warning and the squiggly line, so what I did, I simply saw that vscode is using an old version of typescript so, I click on bottom-right of vscode where it was showing version 3.8.3, and I changed it to the latest version, which was installed with angular, and my problem gets solved.

let me know if it helps and resolved your issue as well.

Thank You

Answer (score 17):

### TLDR

**Import your decorated class into some other file that is already included in TypeScript compilation context which starts from `src/main.ts` file.**

### Explanation

Angular 10 uses TypeScript 3.9 which uses "[Solution style](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-9/#solution-style-tsconfig)" for `tsconfig.json` files. This tsconfig.json file is used by editors and TypeScript’s language server.
Now this file can include several references to other tsconfig files, e.g. `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json`.

Inside those configs we have `files` and `include` options defined like:

```
"files": [
  "src/main.ts",
  "src/polyfills.ts"
],
"include": [
  "src/**/*.d.ts"
]
```

These two options define TypeScript compilation context. Now TypeScript will compile those files and **any files that are referenced from already include in compilation  files**. And your editor also follows that rule.

If you created some file and define some class with decorator but didn't import it in any included in compilation file then you will get error.

> Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to
> change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in
> your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

The reason for this is that for that specific file TypeScript doesn't see `experimentalDecorators` option.

Solution here is: **you should import your class in some other class that is included to compilation context.**

Prior to Angular 10 we had the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
  }
}
```

We don't see any `files` or `include` sections here which means that

**If no 'files' or 'include' property is present in a tsconfig.json, the compiler defaults to including all files in the containing directory and subdirectories except those specified by 'exclude'.**

And that's the reason you didn't see that error in Angular 9. A newly created file was immediately included in compilation context.

Comment: yes you are correct, I was getting error only for newly generated module, after I imported it in app module issue solved.

Comment: this doesn't really help for spec files though.  I'm getting errors in those, but you wouldn't import those anywhere.

Answer (score 16):

It generally happens if you open the vs code from wrong directory. (Eg opening VScode from app folder instead of root).

If directory issue isn't the case, Please restart the Vs code.

If still you are seeing the same issue, then do the following :

- Go to File => Preferences => Settings (or Control+comma) and it will open the User Settings file. Search "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators" and then check the checkbox for experimentalDecorators

or,

- Add the following in VScode settings.json

`"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true`

Comment: Thank you. The problem I experienced stem from opening the project from the wrong folder. I tried opening the project from its parent folder and the errors disappeared.

Comment: tsconfig was already correct, enabling this in settings made the trick  Thanks! (TypeScript version 4.5.2 , VS Code version 1.63.0)

Comment: Appreciate this simple solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please note the open [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18040), as this problem currently has no deep fix for unimported classes.